# Issue while fetching Users data from Azure AD

Tags: java, azure

I am trying to fetch users available in Azure AD. While fetching, `http 401 Authentication Error` Encountered and `IOException` caught on console. Following is the method through which I am trying to fetch data-

```
public String getUsers(String accessToken) {    

    URL url;       
        String line = "";        
        try {
            System.out.println("\n\n***************Available Users ************\n");

                url = new URL("https://graph.windows.net/" + tenant_id 
                        + "/users");


            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Set the appropriate header fields in the request header.
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("api-version", "1.6");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata");

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Responsecode : " + responseCode);

        line=HttpClientHelper.getResponseStringFromConn(con,true);
            System.out.println("Line data"+line);


            /*if (responseCode == 200) {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            } else {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
            }

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }*/

          System.out.println(line);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return line;
    }
```

Comment: 401 error usually means there's something wrong with the token. Please check if the token has not expired. Also check if the user for which token has been acquired has permission to do this operation. Please share more details in your question. You may also want to read the details of the exception. That should give you more information about this error.

Comment: Responsecode : 401
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://graph.windows.net/6b0d2b2e-ac82-4440-b118-81a5206bb678/users
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Through this token I can able to fetch communication API and Management API services.. same token I am using for this code.

Comment: I would suggest checking the permissions for the application in Azure AD and whether permission to  read basic user profiles is selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, you can refer to [Error Handling in OAuth 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645540.aspx) to check your issue.

Meanwhile, as @GauravMantri said, you also need to check the permission of `Microsoft Graph` for application in AAD, please see the figures below.

Fig 1. Checking the permission of application and adding applications
[image]

Fig 2. Click `Add application` and add `Microsoft Graph`
[image]